# Overriding connection pool for datasource with Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

spring boot creates jpa configuration by default for us using application.properties file .
is there any way we can override default data source and can use  Apache dbcp datasouce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions regarding usage of dbcp with spring boot can be seen at https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-oracle-database-commons-dbcp2-example/

Comment: An example _how_ to do this would make your answer even better ;-)